# Example of function with a hundred minima

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Find a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R}$, $f \in C^{\infty}$, such that $\nabla f = 0$ for exactly $100$ points and in these points there are only local minima.

Comment: Yes, I see how it should look like, but i can't find the right formula : (

Comment: Well, you need the troughs, without any peaks.  That would be a neat trick.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg In between the humps it has a critical point that is not a local minimum. Not that easy. Think again.

Comment: avoiding the peaks is easy. it is the mountain passes that are problematic. Otherwise, something like $y^2 + \prod_{k=1}^{100} (x-k)^2$ works.

Comment: For the case of two minima, you have the example $(x^2 - 1)^2 + (x^2 y - x - 1)^2$ which has exactly two critical points, both minima at $(-1, 0)$ and $(1, 2)$. So such functions are possible in $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, though not in $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. This e.g. is from “Two Mountains Without a Valley” proposed and solved by Ira Rosenholtz, Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 60, No. 1, February 1987, p. 48.  For $100$ points, one needs a way to extend it systematically...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy argument for the existence of such a function, even though it does not give any particular formula. Start with a somewhat arbitrary smooth function with at least 100 minima, e.g., $g(x,y) = \cos x \cos y$. Pick a simply connected domain $D$ in the plane which contains exactly 100 minima and no other zeros of the gradient. There exists a smooth diffeomorphism $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \to D$. Now define $f:=g \circ h$, and you have your function. If one starts with a nice function $g$ like the one given, the resulting $f$ will have all minima strict and the critical points all non-degenerate, i.e., the Hessian matrix will be positive definite at all of them.

Answer (score 0):

For $R \rightarrow R$ you can pick the function $1+cos(2\pi x) + ({(x/5^{1/2})}^2)$ to give 10 minima. For $R \rightarrow R^2$ you can let the y factor be $\exp(-y^2)$ or if $C^\infty$ required, the "bump" function. That would ensure the function to only have local minima along the y=0.

Comment: And what do you do about the maxima in between the minima?

Comment: Oh yes forgot that it is not allowed to have maxima. We could divide by a suitable function being 0 for all the maxima which would make the gradient undefined.

Comment: Well, the function also has to be $\in C^\infty$, which means it has to be smooth and defined over all reals.

Comment: No wait, a better approach to let the second factor be a monotonic decreasing function. Like $\exp(-|y|)$.

Comment: Requiring $\in C^\infty$, doesn't that make it impossible? How could you avoid saddle points or maxima in between the minima and still be infinitely differentiable??

Comment: @mathreadler You don't have to have saddles in between minima. The only thing forced by Rolle is that in the lime joining the minima the directional derivative (in that line) vanishes. But in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you still have another transversal direction to get a non-zero gradient.

Comment: Yes. But that transversal direction will climb somewhere. Oh yes, of course it is allowed to climb to infinity. We never said it had to be bounded. Right? So what about $-y(y+sin(x\pi)) + \prod_{k=1}^{100} (x-k)^2$ (some inspiration from achille hui above).

Comment: Dammit. Sorry for the spamming. $-y(sin^2(x\pi)) + \prod_{k=1}^{100} (x-k)^2$

Comment: That last one works except that the local minima $f(k,0)=0$ aren't *strict*, since $f(k,y)=0$ for all $y$ (where $k=1,2,\dots,100$). The question doesn't mention any requirement that the minima should be strict, but it would be even nicer to have such an example.